# Radio Button In Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I just want to ask if I can change the text in radio button.

For example:

[image]

here in the picture if I put a number, it will show the number factors at the radio button. ( the factor 1 will just show in Jlabel and the rest of the factor will show at the Radio button) the problem part at the **private void checkbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)** I already tried to use **.setText()** but I think this will not work for radio button or button group. Is there another way to do that

```
public class primefactor extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form primefactor
     */
    public primefactor() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        numfactorgr = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        checkbtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        cleatbtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        inspectbtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        num1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        numdis = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        numtxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        primeyn = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        numfactors1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        numfactors2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        numfactors3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        numfactors4 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        numfactors = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("NUMBER::");

        jLabel2.setText("FACTORS::");

        jLabel3.setText("PRIME:");

        checkbtn.setText("CHECK");
        checkbtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                checkbtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        cleatbtn.setText("CLEAR");
        cleatbtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cleatbtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        inspectbtn.setText("INSPECT");
        inspectbtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                inspectbtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        numdis.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        numtxt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                numtxtActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        numfactorgr.add(numfactors1);

        numfactorgr.add(numfactors2);

        numfactorgr.add(numfactors3);

        numfactorgr.add(numfactors4);

        numfactors.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(checkbtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 190, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 138, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(cleatbtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 192, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(num1)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(numdis, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                                .addComponent(numfactors, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 184, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                        .addComponent(inspectbtn))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(primeyn)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(numtxt))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(numfactors1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(numfactors2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(numfactors3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(numfactors4)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(numtxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(numdis)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(inspectbtn)
                        .addComponent(num1)
                        .addComponent(numfactors)))
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(primeyn))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 3, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(numfactors1)
                    .addComponent(numfactors2)
                    .addComponent(numfactors3)
                    .addComponent(numfactors4))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(checkbtn)
                    .addComponent(cleatbtn))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void numtxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void checkbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String str = numtxt.getText();
        int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
        int flag = 0;
        
        numdis.setText(str);
        num1.setText("1");
        for (int i=2;i<num;i++){
            if (num%i ==0){
                flag =1;
            num1.setText("1");
            numfactors.setText( numfactors.getText()+i+"    "); // at this part it will display the radio button with the number factors. (but I use first the jlabel numfactors to show the number factors)
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0){
           primeyn.setText("Yes");
        }
        else{
            primeyn.setText(primeyn.getText()+"No");
        }
    }                                        

    private void cleatbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         numtxt.setText("");
        num1.setText("");
        numdis.setText("");
        numfactors.setText("");
        primeyn.setText("");
    }                                        

    private void inspectbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(primefactor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(primefactor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(primefactor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(primefactor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new primefactor().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton checkbtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton cleatbtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton inspectbtn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel num1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel numdis;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup numfactorgr;
    private javax.swing.JLabel numfactors;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton numfactors1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton numfactors2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton numfactors3;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton numfactors4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField numtxt;
    private javax.swing.JLabel primeyn;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: The way you ask is by posting your code in the question, explaining what the code is doing, and explaining what you want the code to do.  [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: You've shot yourself in the foot already by using a form editor, this is going to greatly reduce the flexibility of the solution.  First piece of advice, ditch the form editor